# Entering the password for openssl in command line leads to crash

Tags: openssl, mac

I'm not sure if this is related to .OhMyZsh installation.  Why is my password entry not accepted?

```
➜  Documents openssl rsa -in my_private.pem -noout -text
Enter pass phrase for my_private.pem:
User interface error
4314234176:error:2807106B:UI routines:UI_process:processing error:crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:545:while reading strings
unable to load Private Key
4314234176:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:
4314234176:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:461:
➜  Documents dddd
zsh: command not found: dddd
```

> OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021

**EDIT:**

This is a problem in Mac M1 (Silicon). When I run the terminal under Rosetta, it works fine. I hope someone has a solution to this.

Comment: Use the correct passphrase.

Comment: I can't paste the correct pass phrase in here. `dddd` is just to show you that I have added it.  As I said later the problem is with Mac Silicon. When I run the terminal under Rosetta emulation, it works as expected.  You can clearly see my passphrase entry `dddd` is not passed on and runs as a command of its own.

Comment: Likely you will need to file bug reports, then.